# Android Kotlin Retrofit, wait for response outside suspend

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I've got into a situation where I need to call an endpoint, and wait for the response before continuing the flow

Sadly, I can't make the function 'suspend', since it will require a heavy refactor and I prefer to 'hack' it this once

I've tried waiting for event signal, waiting for a value, using RunBlocking with 'await()', non worked, and await never fires back (response is received when using .enqueue())

All I need is this to work, i don't mind the UI to freeze, the user to wait, or the code to be ugly.
There is a 2 second timeout and its a sacrifice i'm willing to take

I'm not an android (or ios) developer, so i'll be glad to get any tips

Attaching my code:

API Interface

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.POST

interface ITaxForAddressApi {
    @POST("/myapi")
    fun getTaxForAddress(@Body body: TaxForAddressBodyRequest): Call<TaxRateEntity>
}

data class TaxForAddressBodyRequest(
    @SerializedName("address") val address: TaxForAddressBodyAddress
)

data class TaxForAddressBodyAddress(
    @SerializedName("streetAddress") val streetAddress: String,
    @SerializedName("city") val city: String,
    @SerializedName("state") val state: String,
    @SerializedName("zip") val zip: String,
    @SerializedName("country") val country: String
)

data class TaxRateEntity(@SerializedName("tax") val taxRate: Double)
```

Calling code:

```
val addressBody = 
    TaxForAddressBodyAddress(
        shippingAddress.street,
        shippingAddress.city,
        shippingAddress.state,
        shippingAddress.zipCode,
        shippingAddress.country
        )
val taxRequest = TaxForAddressBodyRequest(addressBody)


val taxApiRequest = taxForAddressApi.getTaxForAddress(taxRequest)
taxApiRequest.enqueue(SafeCallback(object : CallbackResponseListener<TaxRateEntity> {
            override fun onSuccess(response: TaxRateEntity) {
                'Do Something here'
            }

            override fun onFailure(t: Throwable) {
                'Alert'
            }
        }))
}
```

Attempt with runBlocking (with try-catch of course):

```
runBlocking {
    val tax = taxForAddressApi.getTaxForAddress(taxRequest).await()
}
```

Comment: Launch a new coroutine instead of runBlocking, it will await for it, and when result has been received you can further process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit's `Call` has an [`execute()`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#execute--) method that you can invoke if you're fine with blocking the calling thread and you need to get the response synchronously. Keep in mind that you might need to disable `StrictMode` which would throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` by default.

Comment: Can't believe I missed it, I thought execute() sends the request asynchronously, thanks!